# Authentication credentials were not provided когда токен передан

Tags: javascript, django, react-native, django-rest-framework, axios

Всем привет. делаю с клиента (react-native приложение) запрос через axios на некий эндпоинт (в куске кода он будет в виде xxx.com). И прокидываю через заголовок авторизации jwt токен. почему-то иногда запрос нормально отрабатывает, но в какой-то момент может возвратиться такая ошибка, как в ней говорится, токен не предоставлен, хотя здесь видно, что он прокинут. П.С. токен не просрочен, в приложении есть axios interceptor который если вернулось 401 обновляет токен и делает запрос еще раз с таким же конфигом. в моем случае из-за этого получается бесконечное вызывание этого запрос ведь он перевызывается каждый раз, возвращая 401. Самое для меня непонятное - это то, что написано в ошибке. Заранее спасибо.

```
{
  "config": {
    "adapter": ["xhr", "http"],
    "baseURL": "https://xxx.com/api",
    "data": undefined,
    "env": {"Blob": [Function Blob], "FormData": [Function FormData]},
    "headers": [Object],
    "maxBodyLength": -1,
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "method": "get",
    "timeout": 0,
    "transformRequest": [[Function transformRequest]],
    "transformResponse": [[Function transformResponse]],
    "transitional": {"clarifyTimeoutError": false, "forcedJSONParsing": true, "silentJSONParsing": true},
    "url": "http://xxx.com/api/users/all/?date_of_birth__year__gte=1963&date_of_birth__year__lte=2005&gender=M&limit=2&offset=2&photo=false",
    "validateStatus": [Function validateStatus],
    "withCredentials": true,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN"
  },
  "data": {"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."},
  "headers": {
    "allow": "GET",
    "cache-control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate",
    "connection": "keep-alive",
    "content-length": "58",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "cross-origin-opener-policy": "same-origin",
    "date": "Sat, 07 Oct 2023 17:52:45 GMT",
    "expires": "0",
    "pragma": "no-cache",
    "referrer-policy": "same-origin",
    "server": "nginx",
    "vary": "origin",
    "www-authenticate": "Bearer realm=\"api\"",
    "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
    "x-frame-options": "DENY"
  },
  "request": {
    "DONE": 4,
    "HEADERS_RECEIVED": 2,
    "LOADING": 3,
    "OPENED": 1,
    "UNSENT": 0,
    "_aborted": false,
    "_cachedResponse": undefined,
    "_hasError": false,
    "_headers": {
      "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjk2NzAxNDY1LCJpYXQiOjE2OTY3MDExNjQsImp0aSI6ImJmNTZiYTE4YzE3NzQ4MjM5N2I3ZDNhY2RhZDNmNjU3IiwidXNlcl9pZCI6ImZlYWIxMTcwLTlkNDYtNGFjYy1iN2VlLWE0Zjg5NDg2NmVkOSJ9.1s_Wdb7ZQGpf1PSr_cL7x55PbEyFBOYUIH9J2CeMrd9E2WS02MbcM08w32Pl123ZJACfyiR0WIXdQOhGIk6z3A"
    },
    "_incrementalEvents": false,
    "_lowerCaseResponseHeaders": {
      "allow": "GET",
      "cache-control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate",
      "connection": "keep-alive",
      "content-length": "58",
      "content-type": "application/json",
      "cross-origin-opener-policy": "same-origin",
      "date": "Sat, 07 Oct 2023 17:52:45 GMT",
      "expires": "0",
      "pragma": "no-cache",
      "referrer-policy": "same-origin",
      "server": "nginx",
      "vary": "origin",
      "www-authenticate": "Bearer realm=\"api\"",
      "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
      "x-frame-options": "DENY"
    },
    "_method": "GET",
    "_perfKey": "network_XMLHttpRequest_http://xxx.com/api/users/all/?date_of_birth__year__gte=1963&date_of_birth__year__lte=2005&gender=M&limit=2&offset=2&photo=false",
    "_performanceLogger": {
      "_closed": false,
      "_extras": [Object],
      "_isLoggingForWebPerformance": false,
      "_pointExtras": [Object],
      "_points": [Object],
      "_timespans": [Object]
    },
    "_requestId": null,
    "_response": "{\"detail\":\"Authentication credentials were not provided.\"}",
    "_responseType": "",
    "_sent": true,
    "_subscriptions": [],
    "_timedOut": false,
    "_trackingName": "unknown",
    "_url": "http://xxx.com/api/users/all/?date_of_birth__year__gte=1963&date_of_birth__year__lte=2005&gender=M&limit=2&offset=2&photo=false",
    "readyState": 4,
    "responseHeaders": {
      "Allow": "GET",
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      "Content-Length": "58",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy": "same-origin",
      "Date": "Sat, 07 Oct 2023 17:52:45 GMT",
      "Expires": "0",
      "Pragma": "no-cache",
      "Referrer-Policy": "same-origin",
      "Server": "nginx",
      "Vary": "origin",
      "WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer realm=\"api\"",
      "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
      "X-Frame-Options": "DENY"
    },
    "responseURL": "https://xxx.com/api/users/all/?date_of_birth__year__gte=1963&date_of_birth__year__lte=2005&gender=M&limit=2&offset=2&photo=false",
    "status": 401,
    "timeout": 0,
    "upload": {},
    "withCredentials": true
  },
  "status": 401,
  "statusText": undefined
}
```

Comment: А что написано в ошибке?

Comment: Проверяйте, нет ли у вас ошибки в коде, при котором токен не отправляется или может быть заменен. Если нет, то обратитесь в поддержку вашего энд поинта за комментариями

Comment: @Глеб "data": {"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."},